# Does have SunOS,Aix,HP the signalfd(), eventfd() APIs?

Tags: linux, api

I know the signalfd(), eventfd() apis in linux OS.
But, I can't find this api in other OS (SunOS, Aix, HP).

Is it only support in Linux??

Comment: eventfd was introduced in Linux at version 2.6.22 which was released on 2007. OS older than 2007 may not have eventfd. (signalfd might be introduced at same time)

Answer (score 1):

Both the [signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) APIs are linux specific.

If you're trying to write portable code; then you're better off sticking to the [POSIX APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). Bear in mind that there can be vagaries in the implementations between platforms.